# Algolia Search Default to a list of my entire Firebase Database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I followed the Algolia Firebase Flutter documentation and inside my app, every time I opened search it defaulted to showing basically my entire database in a list view before I typed anything into the search box. As I typed it would quickly filter the list down.

I have attempted to prevent the entire database from being listed each time a user goes to my search page with this:

```
 Widget _hits(BuildContext context) {
    if (_searchTextController.text.isEmpty) {
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    } else {
      return PagedListView<int, Product>(
        pagingController: _pagingController,
        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Product>(
          noItemsFoundIndicatorBuilder: (_) {

            return const Center(
              child: Text('No results found'),
            );
          },
          itemBuilder: (_, item, __) {
            var convertedWeightList = [];
            var convertedWeightFormatList = [];}}
```

I am just not sure if that is preventing all results to be read from the DB or if its just hiding them all from my view.

If just hiding is there a way for Algolia to not show all when first viewed?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post.  You have two unrelated questions here, and your first question isn't clear.  Of course you are charge for any usage according to the terms of the provide (whether you are talking about Firebase or Algolia is not clear). Your second question is likely a matter of your own app code, is it not? Did you try something that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: removed first question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

try using this library with algolia :https://pub.dev/packages/algolia_helper_flutter

```
final searcher = HitsSearcher.create(
      applicationID: algoliaAppId,
      apiKey: algoliaApiKey,
      state: SearchState(
          facetFilters: ["your_filter"],
          indexName: "enviorenment_name",
          analytics: true,))
```

set search query like this while the user types in a TextformField

```
searcher.query(value);
```

Results can be shown like this,

```
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 1.sw,
      height: 0.8.sh,
      child: StreamBuilder<SearchResponse>(
        stream: searcher.responses,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SearchResponse> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final response = snapshot.data;
            final hits = response?.hits.toList() ?? [];
            isEmptyHits = hits.isEmpty;
            return hits.isEmpty
                ? SizedBox()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: hits.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final hit = hits[index];
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: RichText(
                                    text: TextSpan(
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                                      children: hit.getHighlightedString('title').toInlineSpans(),
                                    ),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Transform.rotate(
                                    angle: 180 * pi / 42,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_upward_sharp,
                                      color: AppColors().grey15,
                                    ))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            height: 1,
                            thickness: 1,
                            color: AppColors().grey4.withOpacity(0.5),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
          } else {
            return const CustomProgressIndicatorWidget();
          }
        },
      ),
    )
```